# Remove row from JQuery DataTable - but it returns as soon as the table is redrawn. Is my .JSP data source the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a button in each row, when pressed that row is removed from one table, and added to another table:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone()
$('.my-other-table-class').append(row);
```

and at first it appears to work perfectly, the row is removed from one table and added to another, but when I force a re-draw (by changing the sorting of one of the columns, for example) all the rows are back as they were, and the buttons no longer work. This is the case for both the removed rows, and the rows added to the other table.

Is this because I'm using a .jsp table as a data-source? Would this work correctly if I dynamically added all the rows to the table using JavaScript at load-time, or if I used a modelMap collection as a data-source?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: It sounds like your event hook is destroyed when the row is removed, and is not re-created when you refresh the table.

Comment: If so, that would explain why the button stops working, but not why the row reappears after being removed. Do I have to set up an 'on redraw' event and manually track what rows should/shouldn't be there?

Comment: I suspect that you will have to manipulate the data in your data source before or as you redraw.

Comment: My data-source is just .jsp rendered as HTML though, does .remove() and .append() not touch that?

Comment: No, it won't touch that.

Comment: But if you use a collection as a data-source, JQuery will modify the collection as it goes? Would adding each row using JavaScript when the page is first loaded solve the problem?

Comment: Someone else may be able to answer that right off, but I would have to see the code in order to give any more advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for future googlers - I have no idea how my google-Fu did not find the answer, I had all the right keywords!

**In short**:

I was doing this to add:

```
$('.my-other-table-class').append(row);
```

And this to remove:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone()
```

but I **should've been doing** this add:

```
$('.my-other-table-class').dataTable().fnAddData([$(this).attr("data-val1"), "var2"]);
```

And this to remove:

```
$('.my-table').dataTable().fnDeleteRow($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
```

**With more detail:**

What I am *really* doing here is modifying the DOM with JQuery (well duh, but I'm really new at this, remember...) - I figured the DOM was the data-source for my table, so that made sense? The table is redrawn, it rereads the DOM and updates? Well not really.

In order to be dynamic, if you use DOM (in other words HTML, or in my case .jsp rendered as HTML) as your data-source, upon initialization, datatables will copy all that information into a JavaScript array.... so rather then my original thought:

"The DOM is not updating correctly, and that issues is propogating up in to my table... because HTML is static...or something?"

it turns out the actual problem was:

"I was updating the DOM, but the *real* data source was a JavaScript array I wasn't seeing. So upon redraw, this array was overwriting the DOM and my changes were being lost."

**TL;DR**: Use the Data-tables API and don't modify the data-source directly, unless you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If the event handlers are one of the issues, it may help to set up your event handler like this:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", "button.moveMe", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone()
    $('.my-other-table-class').append(row);
});
```

This will set a handler on the table that has `id="myTable"`. The handler will look for click events on buttons with the "moveMe" class. It will catch the event on rows that are added later, as well as the rows that exist when this hook is created.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Could you give me a little more information on how this is different from the way I'm doing it?

Comment: All that this does is place the click handler on the table instead of on individual buttons. jQuery then filters the click events down to those which occur on "button" tags with the "moveMe" class and calls the callback when those are encountered. It should speed up your JS when you refresh the tables, because it removes the need to set up click handlers each time.